# Are vertex groups good for rigs?

Tags: rigging, bones

Hi Blender Stack Exchange, I have a reasonably simple question to ask. Is using vertex groups a good option for rigging? I'm not very good at weight painting, and I've found that vertex groups are easy to use. Would this be a viable option?

Thanks!

Comment: Weight painting stores its values inside of vertex groups

Answer (score 0):

I guess most of the time, if you want to rig a manufactured object like a box, robot, machine, etc, parent *With Empty Groups*. It will create a list of vertex groups that will have the same names as the bones except no vertex is assigned to any of these vertex groups for the moment, you need to select the vertices, go into the *Object Data > Vertex Groups*, select the vertex group you want your vertices to be part of and click on *Assign*:

[image]

For organic things like plants, animal, humans, etc, you should rather parent *With Automatic Weights*, it will automatically assign the vertices to a series of vertex groups that will have the same names as the bones. You may need to give some correction in *Weight Paint* mode though. Also, for the small details (like fingers) you may need to switch to the first method.

[image]